# Make mac os x apache use existing mysql

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

Normally I use XAMPP with its php and mysql instances and that works fine - but for various reasons I need to use Mac OS X's built in apache for a change. I have set that up and it works fine, but now I guess I also need to set up the according mysql server? I would like it to use my existing mysql server that I also use with xampp.

My existing mysql server seems to be located at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/

How can I make apache use that mysql server for databases?

I know these questions are those of an absolute beginner, but it's been years since I last did this.

Comment: Did you try to export the whole of old database and import it to new mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is confusing (How can I make apache use that mysql server for databases?)

You are connecting to Mysql from PHP. Not from Apache.

Use the details of existing mysql server in your application config files (Normally config.php in a PHP application).

Comment: I should have added that I am using Symfony (for the first time). I needed to give the database path in the parameters.yml file - now it works fine. Thanks for your help! :)